# Ordering Users for use in view

Tags: 7, users, views

I have a view that displays data for each user. Now I would like to be able to order the users.

One solution would be to add a new field called something like `field_weight` to the user content type and then use this field to sort the view, but preferably I would like to do this through drag and drop from the `admin/people` configuration page.

I installed the [weight](https://drupal.org/project/weight) module, but it doesn't seem to support setting the weight for a user.

Is there a module that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I haven't misunderstood your question and you're using `Views`, you could simply sort the view by your `weight_field` and then just assign the right weight parameter to the user.

If you prefer some kind of drag and drop functionality (which in my opinion is easier to manage than weight) you could use [Draggable Views](https://drupal.org/project/draggableviews), this module will allow you to have a view where you can order your users display, a good tutorial I used as a first timer is [this](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/custom-sort-drupal-content-draggable-views-module).

Comment: Yes, I understood I could add my own field and sort by it in the view, but I would really like use drag and drop for this one.

Comment: Then I think `draggable views` is what you're looking for.